# C# - Which is syntax in LINQ to EF for this query?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have two table 
`Teachers(**int IDT**, int mat, String name )` and `Courses(String name, **int IDT**)`. IDT is FKey in Courses and PKey in Teachers.
Then the teacher cant are in more that 3 courses. My query work fine in sql. My question is, '**How write this in LINQ to EF**'?

```
select p.name, p.mat, p.IDT, count(c.IDT) from Teachers p 
left join courses c on c.IDT = p.IDT 
group by p.name, p.mat, p.IDT 
having count(c.IDT) <3
```

Comment: I dont know to convert my query for LINQ to EF format. Only this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try as shown below.

```
     from p in context.Teachers
     join c in context.courses on c.IDT equals p.IDT into j1
     from j2 in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()
     group j2 by new { p.name, p.mat, p.IDT } into grouped
                 let theCount = grouped.Sum(e => e != null ? 1 : 0)
                 where  theCount <  3

    select new { Name = grouped.Key.name, Mat= grouped.Key.mat,
                 Idt=grouped.Key.IDT,Count = theCount }
```

Comment: Will try in this week... Sorry me late. Thanks